# If $f, g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are measurable, is the product $F(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need help with how to approach a homework problem. The question is:

Suppose $f, g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are measurable functions. Determine whether the following statement is true or false: "The function $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$ is measurable." If true, provide a proof, if false provide a counterexample.

I haven't been able to construct a counterexample, so I think that it's true, but I have no idea how to show it. How could I start?

Comment: Do you know that measurable functions are a.e. limits of step functions?

Comment: "measurable" means Lebesgue measurable?  That is, $\{(x,y) : f(x)g(y) \le t\}$ is measurable for two-eimensional Lebesgue measure?

Comment: I believe this is done in the book "elements of integration" writed by Bartle

Comment: @Care Bear Yes, I know that

Comment: @GEdgar, yes, Lebesgue measurable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lambda=0$, then $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)>0\}=(\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)>0\}\times\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)>0\})\cup(\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)<0\}\times\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)<0\})$. 
Since $f,g$ are measurable, then $\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)>0\},\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)>0\},\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)<0\}\quad and\quad\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)<0\}$ are measurable sets. Thus $\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)>0\}\times\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)>0\}$ and $\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)<0\}\times\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)<0\}$ are measurable. Therefore, $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)>0\}$ is measurable.

If $\lambda>0$, then

$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}|F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)>\lambda\}
=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|f(x)>\lambda/g(y),g(y)>0\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}|f(x)<\lambda/g(y),g(y)<0\}
=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(\{x\in\mathbb{R}|f(x)>r_{i}\}\times\{y\in\mathbb{R}|\lambda/g(y)\leq r_{i},g(y)>0\})\cup(\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)<r_{i}\}\times\{y\in\mathbb{R}|r_{i}<\lambda/g(y),g(y)<0\}),r_{i}\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Since $f,g$ are measurable, then

$(\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)>r_{i}\}\times\{y\in\mathbb{R}|\lambda/g(y)\leq r_{i},g(y)>0\})\cup(\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)<r_{i}\}\times\{y\in\mathbb{R}|r_{i}<\lambda/g(y),g(y)<0\})$ is measurable. Thus when $\lambda>0$,$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)>\lambda\}$ is measurable.

Similarly, we can prove that $\lambda<0$, $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)>\lambda\}$ is measurable.

Thus, $F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

I'ts easier to prove that if $f$ measurable then $f^2$ measurable. Use the fact that  $2fg = (f+g)^2 - f^2 - g^2$

Comment: That's correct, but not what the question is asking. It's asking about a function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Here let $f$ and $g$ be considered functions of two variables, just not depending on the other variable.  Then this is fine.  I guess there is another step: if $f(x)$ is measurable as a function of $x$, then it also is measurable as a function of $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the type of question where something funny in mathematics happens. It is actually easier to prove something stronger (provided you know some topology)!

> If $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $F=\Phi(f_1(x),f_2(y))$, where $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is continuous and $f_1, f_2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are measurable, then $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

**Proof:** We define $K: (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow (f_1(x),f_2(y))\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Clearly, $F=\Phi\circ K$. Let $O$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. We have:

$$F^{-1}(O)=K^{-1}(\Phi^{-1}(O))=K^{-1}(\tilde{O})$$

Where $\tilde{O}=\Phi^{-1}(O)$ is open because of continuity of $\Phi$. Next, any open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is writen as $\tilde{O}=\cup_{i=1}^\infty I_{1i}\times I_{i_2}$, where $I_{ji}=B(q_{ij},r_{ij})$ are open balls in $\mathbb{R}$ with rational center and radius ($\mathbb{R}^2$ is a second-countable space). Hence:

$$F^{-1}(O)=K^{-1}(\cup_{i=1}^\infty I_{1i}\times I_{i_2})=\cup_{i=1}^\infty K^{-1}(I_{1i}\times I_{i_2})=\cup_{i=1}^\infty f_{1}^{-1}(I_{i1})\times f_2^{-1}(I_{i2})$$

This last element is clearly in the sigma algebra. $\square$

---

Answer (score -1):

If $\lambda=0$, then $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)>0\}=(\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)>0\}\times\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)>0\})\cup(\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)<0\}\times\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)<0\})$. Since $f,g$ are measurable, then $\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)>0\},\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)>0\},\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)<0\}\quad and\quad\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)<0\}$ are measurable sets. Thus $\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)>0\}\times\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)>0\}$ and $\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)<0\}\times\{y\in \mathbb{R}|g(y)<0\}$ are measurable. Therefore, $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)>0\}$ is measurable. \
If $\lambda>0$, then $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)>\lambda\}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|f(x)>\lambda/g(y),g(y)>0\}\cup\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|f(x)<\lambda/g(y),g(y)<0\}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)>r_{i}\}\times\{y\in\mathbb{R}|\lambda/g(y)\leq r_{i},g(y)>0\})\cup(\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)<r_{i}\}\times\{y\in\mathbb{R}|r_{i}<\lambda/g(y),g(y)<0\}),r_{i}\in \mathbb{Q}$. Since $f,g$ are measurable, then $(\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)>r_{i}\}\times\{y\in\mathbb{R}|\lambda/g(y)\leq r_{i},g(y)>0\})\cup(\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)<r_{i}\}\times\{y\in\mathbb{R}|r_{i}<\lambda/g(y),g(y)<0\})$ is measurable. Thus when $\lambda>0$,$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)>\lambda\}$ is measurable. \
Similarly, we can prove that $\lambda<0$, $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)>\lambda\}$ is measurable. \
Thus, $F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ is measurable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is essentially unreadable.